# The dolphindb equivalent for pandas pct_change function

Tags: python, rolling-computation, dolphindb

In python, I can use the following script to calculate the price volatility (measured by standard deviation) of a stock in 250 days:

```
data.get("close").pct_change().rolling(250,min_periods=100).std()
```

How can I perform the same operation in DolphinDB?

Comment: exort the data into a pandas dataframe and execute the same code as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pct_change` means `(x(n) - x(n-1))/x(n-1)`. It is equivalent to `x(n) / x(n-1) - 1`, which can be performed by DolphinDB's function `ratios`.

The DolphinDB script below is equivalent to the python script you provided:

```
def calc(x){
        y = ratios(x) - 1
        return mstd(y, 3, 2)
}
calc(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
percentChange(85 90 95);

[,0.058824,0.055556]
```